# Spyder variable explorer stuck on showing always the same variables each time I run the program

Tags: spyder

As in the title, each time I run Spyder (new session) it shows always a list of variables (belonging to Numpy, matpolotlib etc.) and I cannot erase them all together (while it is possible to do it manually). However, even done so, they will reappear at the next session.
Does anyone know what happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This happens (most probably) because you have the Pylab option activated:

[image: Pylab]

That option imports Numpy and Matplotlib to all your consoles. And those imports create several objects that are the ones shown in the Variable Explorer by default.